# Deselect a checkbox

Tags: jquery

Im not sure why but for some reason when I click a td that has its checkbox already checked it does NOT deselect it.

```
$('table tr').click(function() {

    checkBox = $(this).children('td').children('input[type=checkbox]');

    if(checkBox.attr('checked'))
        checkBox.attr('checked', '');
    else
        checkBox.attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want:

```
   if(checkBox.attr('checked'))
        checkBox.removeAttr('checked');
    else
        checkBox.attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery v1.6, you should be using `.prop()`

```
if(checkBox.prop('checked'))
    checkBox.prop('checked', false)
else
    checkBox.prop('checked', true);
```